# Is it possible to create a function that returns a different struct based on an enum input in Unreal?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So I am working on a data driven game in Unreal and essentially I am working more on the back end trying to make it easier for the objects to get all of the relevant data. I was really trying to create a singular function that by passing in a type I could return a different output but, from what I've tried in the editor this doesn't seem possible.

[image: Function with wildcard]

I get the error: **The type of  Out Struct  is undetermined.  Connect something to  Return Node  to imply a specific type.** I was trying to use a wildcard as an output but, it doesn't seem to be able to do that. Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you make both of those structs inherit from a common (parent) struct, you can have the function return type be of that parent struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, just make base struct and inherit your *Config structs from it. In return you will send base struct.

You can read more about this solution here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern